# javascript surprising array comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I'm trying to compare two arrays in javascript.

What I'd like is:

> a < b ⇔ ∃ i ≥ 0 s.t. a[i] < b[i] and ∀ 0 ≤ j < i, a[j] = b[j]

So arrays of non-negative numbers work as desired:

```
firebug> [0,1,2,3,4] < [1,0,0]
true
```

And comparing negative numbers with zero works as expected:

```
firebug> [-1, 1] < [0, 0]
true
```

But comparing negative numbers with negative numbers is... suprising:

```
firebug> [-2] < [-1]
false
firebug> -2 < -1
true
```

What's going on here, so I can correct my intuition for what array comparison **means** in javascript?

Comment: See also [How are arrays compared in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16566772/1048572) for an explanation of the behaviour and [Three-way compare function for Arrays in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23881838/1048572) for a solution

Comment: Specification is here: [abstract operation IsLessThan](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The array is converted to a string, which comes down to `.join()`, which in turn joins the elements with a comma (`,`) as delimiter.

```
"-1,1" < "0,0" === true
```

because the *character code* of `-` (45) is smaller than the *character code* of `0` (48).

On the other hand,

```
"-2" < "-1" === false
```

because the second character codes are compared (the first are both `-`, so that doesn't give a result yet), and the character code for `2` (50) is *bigger* than the character code of `1` (49), so this yields `false`.

It comes down to a lexographical sorting (i.e. by character codes) and not a numerical one, even if the elements are numbers (because of the string coercion).

Basically comparing arrays is not recommended. It is implicitly defined as string comparison, but this can yield surprising results.

Comment: @jAndy: It would, but then again it only works nicely for one-element arrays. `-2 - 1` would be a bit clearer...

Answer (score 9):

There's no such thing as JavaScript array comparison in any form similar to what you describe.

What's happening in all cases is that your arrays are being converted first to strings by joining their contents together. Thus, the string "-2" is **not** less than the string "-1", because the character "2" comes after "1" in the character set. Similarly, "-1,1" is less than "0,0" because the "-" character comes before the digits.

You can see for yourself that in all cases your comparisons:

```
array1 < array2
```

get exactly the same results as:

```
("" + array1) < ("" + array2)
```

or:

```
array1.join(",") < array2.join(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find an answer about how to actually compare arrays in Javascript and get "expected" results, so here is the code

```
compareArrays = function(a, b) {
  var elA, elB, i, len; 
  for (i = 0, len = Math.min(a.length, b.length); i < len; i++) {               
    elA = a[i], elB = b[i];
    if (elA > elB) return 1;
    if (elA < elB) return -1;
  }
  return b.length - a.length;
};

console.log(compareArrays([-2], [-1])) # -1
console.log(compareArrays([], [])) # 0
console.log(compareArrays([null], [undefined])) # 0
console.log(compareArrays([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])) # 1
console.log(compareArrays([0, 2], [0, 1])) # 1
console.log(compareArrays([1], [NaN])) # 0
console.log(compareArrays([NaN], [1])) # 0
```