# How are Javascript array compared?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cmp

Is there a standard defined how would JavaScript be compared, on Chrome console I get this

```
[10,0,0] > [1,0,0]
true
[10,0,0] > [5,0,0]
false
[5, 0, 0, 0] < [10, 0, 0, 0] //repeatable
false

[10,0,0,0] > [9,0,0,0]
false
[11,0,0,0] > [10,0,0,0]
true
```

Which is highly unintutive, and I can't even make sense what logic is being applied, and they look repeatable so doesn't look based on object id(ref) etc, so is there any documentation for it?

Comment: Well, maybe ECMAScript specs will help: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5

Comment: Is it implicitly calling toString and comparing alphabetically?

Comment: This answer on similar question can be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8329014/2393432

Comment: you can see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: One more thread might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are converted to strings and the strings are then compared. So.

```
[10,0,0].toString() => "10,0,0"
[5,0,0].toString() => "5,0,0"
```

Strings are compared lexicographically, so "5,0,0" is bigger than "10,0,0".

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may help you,

```
JSON.stringify([2,2,2]) === JSON.stringify([2,2,2]); //true
```

Cheers :).

Comment: Why would this help him?

Comment: By this we can straight away compare two array as String.