# Ordering lists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I have a list whose members are nested lists of integers, for example :

```
[ [1,2], [], [1,2,3], [ [1,2],3], [1,2,4], [ [], [1,2] ], [34,5,6], [-1,66] ]
```

I want to sort this list, using (what every other language in the world) would consider standard ordering of nested lists. For example :

```
[] < [ [1] ] < [ [1,2] ] < [ [2] ] < [ [11] ]
```

`l.sort()` messes this up, because it turns the lists into strings

Is there an easy way, either in javascript (or a common library like lodash) to get a proper sort of nested lists?

Comment: I'm not seeing lodash `_.sort()` in either version 2, 3 or 4 - which function specifically are you using?

Comment: The 11 before 2 is because your array contents are probably strings, not numbers. Use `parseInt` in your comparer or map with parseInt beforehand.

Comment: lodash doesn't have a sort at all, I'm using javascript sort currently.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23883042/1048572). Btw, every other language would gag on inhomogeneously nested lists. It's not even intuitive whether `[1, [2, 3], 4]` would be larger than `[1, [2], 3, 4]` or not. Do you just want to flatten them?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Here's an easy option, let's go with what python says (other languages, like GAP, agree)

[[], [-1, 66], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [34, 5, 6], [[], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], 3]]

In general python defines recursively. Go through each element of the array, All integers sort smaller than all arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a system of two mutually recursive functions, the first one compares arrays to non-arrays and numbers to numbers, the second compares arrays elementwise.

```js
function cmp(x, y) {
    let ax = Array.isArray(x),
        ay = Array.isArray(y);
    return ax - ay || (ax ? cmpArr(x, y) : x - y);
}

function cmpArr(x, y) {
    let xlen = x.length,
        ylen = y.length,
        min = xlen < ylen ? xlen : ylen,
        c;

    for (let i = 0; i < min; i++) {
        if (c = cmp(x[i], y[i]))
            return c;
    }

    return xlen - ylen;
}

//

a = [[1, 2], [], [1, 2, 3], [[1, 2], 3], [1, 2, 4], [[], [1, 2]], [34, 5, 6], [-1, 66]];
a.sort(cmp);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. It's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : Okay, inspired by @Damien's answer, this is dirty but will work perfectly. Wish I had managed something cleaner.

You might be able to use [lodash's differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceWith) to 'compress' the array for each values wich are equals. But jsfiddle doesn't have the latest version of lodash so I can't test it.

```
var l = [[1,2],[],[1,3],[34, 5, 6],[-1, 66]];

l = l.sort(function(a, b) {

  var minLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) { // Compare the "matching pairs"
    if (a[i] < b[i]) {
      return -1;
    } else if(a[i] > b[i]){
        return 1;
    }
  }

  return a.length - b.length; // If all pairs were equals, use list length
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/1328/#&togetherjs=KFoUJQemH5)

Comment: My bad. Fixed. It now uses the first number of every array.

Comment: My example was too simple -- my lists can have the same first element, for example I could have elements [1,2,3,4] and [1,2,3,5]

Answer (score 1):

You can use _.sortBy as a shortcut.

```
_.sortBy(arr, function (o) { return o[0] || Infinity } )
```

Or, if your interior arrays are not yet sorted:

```
_.sortBy(arr, function (o) { return someMutatedArr[0] || Infinity } )
```

**EDIT:**

I found a better way that sorts beyond the first item in the list, but the empty array is still at the end. You could handle this as an edge case separately, annoying, I know.

```
var arr = [ [11], [1,3], [2], [], [1], [1,2]]
var count = []

// Get an array that is as long as the longest array with [0, 1, 2, etc]
arr.forEach(function (e, i) { 
  if (e.length > (count.length) ) 
    count.push(count.length -1) 
})

_.sortBy(arr, count)
```

Comment: You can't just only consider the first element of the inner arrays, consider for example sorting `[ [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,4] ]`

Comment: Slightly improved solution above. Handling the empty array is just not happening for me, but this will pass your case of `[1,2,3,4/5]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom sort function, see this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Example:

```
var l = [[1,2], [], [34,5,6], [-1,66]];

l = l.sort(function (a, b) {

  if(!a.length) {
      return -1; 
  }

  if(!b.length) {
      return 1; 
  }

  return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

You probably have to handle more edge cases, but you have the idea here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = _.chain(items)
    .groupBy(function (item) {
        return _.chain(item).flattenDeep().max().value() || -1;
    })
    .map(function(val, key){
        return {
            key: parseFloat(key),
            val: val
        };
    })
    .orderBy('key')
    .map(function(item){
        return _.sortBy(item.val, 'length');
    })
    .flatten()
    .value();
```

for

```
[[], [ [1] ], [ [1,2] ], [ [2] ], [ [11] ]]
```

result is

```
[ [], [ [ 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 2 ] ], [ [ 2 ] ], [ [ 11 ] ] ]
```

Comment: Have you just struck it lucky here, that the largest and smallest elements in my arrays help you sort? In general I might have the lists [1,2,10] and [1,3,5], and [1,2,10] should come first. Is it non-obvious what ordering I want?