# Sort an array of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort an array of arrays with integers inside, for example:

```
var array = [[123, 3], [745, 4], [643, 5], [643, 2]];
```

How can I sort it in order to return something like the following?

```
array = [[745, 4], [643, 2], [643, 5], [123, 3]];
```

Comment: Are you sorting by the first element in each array, or the largest element in each array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an array with arrays in it by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435228/sort-an-array-with-arrays-in-it-by-string)

Comment: @mhodges sorting by the first element in each array

Comment: Note that this is essentially the same as [Sorting objects by property values](/q/2466356/4642212). If you’re looking for sorting an array _based on another array_ (e.g. `const order = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];` defines the order and you want to sort `[ "blue", "green", "red" ]` according to `order`), then see [Sort array based on another array](/q/13304543/4642212).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can pass a custom comparison function to `Array.prototype.sort()`, like so:

```
var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
```

This would sort an array of integers in ascending order. The comparison function should return:

- an integer that is less than `0` if you want `a` to appear before `b`
- an integer that is greater than `0` if you want `b` to appear before `a`
- `0` if `a` and `b` are the same

So, for this example you would want something like:

```
var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[0] - a[0];
});
```

If you wanted to sort on both elements of each sub-array (ie. sort by the first element descending, then if they are the same then sort by the second element descending), you could do this:

```
var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a[0] == b[0]) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
  }
  return b[0] - a[0];
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort for more info.

Comment: I noticed that comparison operators can be applied to arrays and it works, however it's not documented anywhere, e.g. `[2, 2] > [1, 3]` is true and `[1, 0] > [0, 1]` is true... etc.

Comment: +1 to @CMCDragonkai's comment. Using the `>` and `<` operators you can explicitly return `1, -1, or 0` from the compare function.

Comment: Please don't use the `<` operator - it isn't correct in all situations. The arrays are implicitly stringified via `.join(',')` before comparing (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328908/javascript-surprising-array-comparison).

This means that `[11, 2] < [2, 3] == true` which is not what you want.

Comment: Be careful: `Array.prototype.sort()` sorts the array in-place. The assignment to `sortedArray` is a bit misleading. To return a new array you should use `toSorted()` instead. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted

Answer (score 12):

You can use `sort` method and first sort by first elements and then by second.

```js
var array = [[123, 3], [745, 4], [643, 5], [643, 2]];
array.sort(([a, b], [c, d]) => c - a || b - d);
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want to sort by the first index in your example, the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function exists to solve your problem.

```
let ans = [[123, 3], [745, 4], [643, 5], [643, 2]].sort( (a, b) => {
  return b[0] - a[0]
})

console.log(ans)
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution for the arrays with generic lengths (not limited to 2 or equal) can be as below:

```js
var array = [[123, 3], [745, 4], [643, 5], [643, 2]];
array.sort((a,b)=>
    {
        for(let i=0;i<a.length && i<b.length;i++){
            if(a[i]!==b[i]){
                return a[i]-b[i];
            }

        }
        return a.length-b.length;
    }
)
console.log(array)
```

Comment: excellent answer, it is mising the closing ) however, very useful... kudos

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort sub array in ascending order as per first element,
we can do :

```
arrayToSort.sort((a, b) =>a[0] - b[0]);
```