# Compare an array of arrays to check if the arrays are in order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays like this, `const array = [[1,5],[7,9],[10,14]];` I need to check to see if the arrays are in order.

Basically, for the provided array, I need to compare the first array's second value, (5), with the second array's first value, (7), which I would then use to invalidate a form.

If the arrays or in order, `const array = [[1,5],[6,9],[10,14]];` it returns false, it passes validation, if they aren't, validation fails and it returns true.

So far, I've done something like this.

```
const arrayIdxZeroValues = [];
const arrayIdxOneValues = []; 
array.forEach((arr,idx) => {
  arrayIdxZeroValues.push(arr[0])
  arrayIdxOneValues.push(arr[1])
})
```

which separates the values fine. I then thought about using `.shift()` to remove the first value of arrayIdxZeroValues since it will never need to be compared, but I feel this is hacky and I'm not sure it's the right approach from here. Maybe `.reduce()` to compare the output arrays, but I haven't been able to get it to work right.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415200/sort-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could check the actual value agains the last value of the previous array plus one and omit the check for the first inner array.

```js
const
    inOrder = array => array.every(([v], i, a) => !i || a[i - 1][1] + 1 === v);

console.log(inOrder([[1, 5], [7, 9], [10, 14]]));
console.log(inOrder([[1, 5], [6, 9], [10, 14]]));
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help! If you find the time, I'd love an explanation of the implementation.

Comment: I'm still getting a true value returned when there are no gaps, however. ```const array = [[1, 5], [6, 9], [10, 14]]```

Comment: it looks like `true`. do you want `false`? why?

Comment: because I need to determine if the subarrays are continuous. In your example array, there is a gap between 5 and 7, so it should return true, as it does. In my example there is no gap, 5 to 6, 9 to 10, and so one. This should return false, meaning there is no gap between the subarrays.

Comment: do you need only to check the gaps? or if the value inside of the array are greater than the first value?

Answer (score 1):

Create an array that starts from the 2nd sub-array using `Array.slice()`. Use `Array.some()` and check if the 2nd item of the current sub-array is equal or less the 2nd item of the sub-array at the current index `i` of the original array. In this way you compare the 2nd with the 1st, the 3rd with the 2nd, and so on.

`false` - means the validation passed
`true` - means validation failed

```js
const isFailed = arr => arr.slice(1)
  .some(([n], i) => n !== arr[i][1] + 1)


console.log(isFailed([[1,5],[6,9],[10,14]])) // false
console.log(isFailed([[1,5],[7,9],[10,14]])) // true
```

Comment: Thanks Ori, but I don't believe this works given the criteria. The first array, [1,5] would need to then start with a 6, [6,9] to pass validation. Given that array, the third array would need to start with 10, [10,14], and so on for an undetermined number of subarrays

Comment: So the distance between last and 1st should be 1 always?

Comment: yes. Basically, continuous. The sub array values represent ranges, with a lower and upper value. They can't overlap, for example, [[1,4], [4,7], .........] wouldn't qualify. The second subarray would need to be a 5, [5,7]. If it's [6,7] that wouldn't qualify either. And the number of subarrays has no limit.

Comment: Updated the answer. What is that used for? and why do you want `false` when the criteria is met, and `true` when it fails?

Comment: Thanks again! I use it in a form validation. The way the validation works, is if it return true, it throws a form error. For example, if the input field is required, and the value === '', the logic return true and the form renders the UI message.