# JavaScript formal criteria definition of array comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays

Today working with task on JS I found that JavaScript out of the box have powerful comparison of arrays:

```
console.log(["a","b"] > ["a","aa"] && ['a','aa'] < ['a', 'cc']) // true
```

This leads to shortcut sorting for two dimensional arrays with strings

```
console.log([["a","aa"],['b','bb'],["a","c"],['b',"ab"],['b',"a"]].sort())
/*
[ [ 'a', 'aa' ],
  [ 'a', 'c' ],
  [ 'b', 'a' ],
  [ 'b', 'ab' ],
  [ 'b', 'bb' ] ]*/
```

JavaScript automatically order sub arrays with similar first element.
Now I'm seek for **formal definition** how do JavaScript compares two arrays.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328908/javascript-surprising-array-comparison

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript surprising array comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328908/javascript-surprising-array-comparison) and [How do I compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566772)

Comment: Don't use quotes around names. Just say simply, JavaScript, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By taking [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), you get the following [Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) to the use of the parameter `compareFunction`:

> If `compareFunction` is not supplied, all non-undefined array elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in UTF-16 code units order. For example, "banana" comes before "cherry". In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order. All `undefined` elements are sorted to the end of the array.

The result is an array which looks like sorted, at least for the first element unless the elements contains commas.

Answer (score 1):

The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. The default sort order is built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

See [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)